# reactjs - How to pass an object between screens of the same hierarchy

Tags: reactjs

I have a login screen and a password screen.
When I access the login screen and log in, it returns a response. I need to pass this answer to the password screen, because I will need two data that are inside the object to register the password.
However, the two screens have the same hierarchy within the code.

The image below shows the hierarchy of the two screens within the code:

[image]

Comment: You will need to use a [common parent](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to be responsible for managing that data, or use [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext).

Comment: What kind of data you wana pass? If it's a string (looks like email in your case) you can pass that using query params, otheriwise you have to use a common parent or context API.

Comment: I didn't know the context, I'm researching it and I think it will solve my problem